# Angularjs with redux

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, redux

I have been reading some on Redux. Most of what I read is combining redux with react.  I use Angularjs.  Is there a good reason to use Redux vs just managing state within angularjs scope and allowing angular to manage the bindings

Comment: Redux is intended to be used with view libraries (like the aforementioned React). Angular is far more than just a view library, it's a framework. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with Redux that you're not able to solve with Angular already? It seems like mixing the two would involve a lot of feature overlap / code duplication.

Comment: Nothing.  I just did a quick google for angularjs and redux.  There were articles on using redux to manage state in angular and I wondered , why you would do this.   I think you answered my question.

Comment: Honestly, I've never thought to mix the two :). I can't comment on any potential benefits, just seems like a weird pairing. Do you have links to the articles you mentioned?

Comment: Perhaps that could be useful as a way to gradually port/transition an existing Angular app to Redux/React.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Redux has benefits with Angular 1.x if you have a lot of shared state. In the Angular app I work on we have many pages with a shared model and several components that make (overlapping) changes to that model. It's not always easy to keep that data in sync or to have a standard way for changes to happen. Redux is a nice way to do that, though you could certainly implement something similar just using Angular services. The one-way data flow that Redux uses is easier (in my opinion) to follow than what you normally do in Angular. Conversely, introducing Redux probably hurts your ability to write really quick prototypes, since there's a bit more work to pass data around. That doesn't matter to me, but might matter to others.

The main [principles of Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html) still apply in Angular apps:

- Single source of truth (single state object). Like I said above, I think it's easier to manage state when it's in a single place versus managed in different Angular scopes or services. Scope-soup is a real problem in some apps.
- State is immutable. This one is where most of the friction with Angular comes in, since Angular (and Javascript) make mutating data really easy. But it does help you write safer code. Since you can only change an immutable object by creating a copy, you can be more confident any data manipulation you're doing in a directive isn't going to break other directives. And conversely, you can expect that other directives aren't making modifications to your data. All of those modifications go through a central place (the single state object, via reducers), so it's easier to find them.
- Changes are made by pure functions. I think this is useful in any JS application. The more code you have that doesn't have a bunch of side effects or framework dependencies, the easier your app is to understand and test. A lot of our tests for Angular code have a bunch of app setup boilerplate. Testing a reducer is incredibly simple by comparison, since it's just a Javascript function.

Using Redux means less of your code is Angular-centric. This means you have an easier upgrade path if you decide to not use Angular. Or even if you just want to migrate to Angular 2. How much easier is hard to say, though.

I don't think there's a ton of overlap due to Angular being more of a framework than a library, but there are things in Redux you can't take as much advantage of in Angular. You might know precisely what part of your app state is changing, but Angular is going run its digest cycle and check everything anyway. Angular 2 is better in that regard, though. You're going to have to jump through some hoops to make all your directives work with immutable data. And especially if you want to send every field a user changes through the Redux store, since ng-model wants to mutate the property you pass it.

Every app is different, but using Redux makes sense in the type of Angular apps I've worked on.

Comment: JeffB you mentioned sending every field a user changes though the store.  Is this a case by case basis? I guess its up to the designer to determine what level of application state they want to retain, correct?

Comment: Yeah, it would depend on your requirements, or just developer preference. It is hard to save each user input change in the Redux store, because ng-model is mutating your data directly. It's easier to create a mutable copy when a user needs to enter form data, then save the result into the Redux store when they're done. But you might have requirements that don't work with that approach.

Comment: I figured as much.  If you could, I have the following question out there. Any advice would be appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/q/37265869/684869

Comment: @JeffB So if you apply the 'single source of truth' concept to an Angular app without actually using ngRedux or ReduxJS, where would you create that single source? As different elements on the parent scope? As a store on the parent scope (e.g. `$scope.$parent.store = {prop1: true,...}`)? A separate global variable or what?

Comment: @Rozgony you can create myappStateService and use it as a single state of truth, right? Definitely not in rootScope (which is exactly some kind of global variable).

Answer (score 0):

Redux can be used with any javascript technology. In summary you can integrate it into an Agular project. Nowadays, it is transforming the way applications are built. It enables a new way to conceive applications by using an unidirectional dataflow. As a result, this gives you better control over your application state and tools to eradicate issues associated to data mutability. Take a look at this great [tutorial about using Redux in Angular projects](https://blog.uruit.com/2017/05/04/using-redux-angular/).

Comment: that article is Angular 2+, OP asked specifically for angularjs (1.x)