# Angular Forms with Redux

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular, redux

Looking for some advice when working with Redux, and Angular.  I've been researching Redux for the past couple of days and really think its a great way to store application data.  The part I'm having trouble with is whether to persist everything within the store or only certain parts.  Ideally, I think the entire application should be running through the store, but for forms this seems very tedious.

For example, lets say I'm working with a form to add a new product. Here are some of my pain points.

- I would like to keep the User Reducer (store) separated from the actual form state. Should I create a separate form reducer per component?
- Having to persist every input field back to the store sounds like a lot of work.  I've seen the library [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) simplifies this, but is intended for React.

Anyone have any good advice when it comes to creating forms in Angular with Redux?

Comment: I'm also looking to redux to simplify data flow in my company's angular 1.5 app, but having trouble getting passed the "persist every input field back to the store". Have you come up with anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I think the best approach to simply avoid storing form input in a store.

Comment: Suspected that. Cool, thanks

Comment: I disagree. If the source of truth is the angular form, you end up putting a lot of logic in the controller (to sync it with other redux state). That's what we're trying to avoid in the first place. So for all but the simplest forms, put state in redux.

Comment: Updating the store on each keydown seems a bit unnecessary.  But if it's something you want to support for you application I don't see a problem with it.  Take for example moving an element on the screen with the mouse, you wouldn't send mouse coordinates to the store every time the mouse moved, only when the element was moved.  However, if you wanted to persist state of users moving their mouse while viewing your site, this seems acceptable.  In general, syncing form state is unnecessary. @UAvalos could you elaborate on what you mean by syncing it with other redux state?

Comment: If the form is the source of truth and redux is the source of truth, there is extra work to keep those in sync. For example, in my use case, the form is "settings". However, redux also holds logic used by the rest of the app to keep the settings in valid state (i.e., update outside of the form). Hence, there is now extra work to keep the two in sync.

Comment: I don't think the form should be the source of truth.  It only displays what the store contains, and is updated when the user clicks "Update".  If someone else updates the values in the store, the form should refresh with those changes.  My original point is, you wouldnt want to dispatch an action every time someone presses a key.

Comment: well what if what the form shows depends on something else? The logic to keep the form and the other state in sync gets complex really quick. That's the whole point of redux but by using an Angular form, you give that up

Comment: If the business need requires it then sure.  For instance, an auto complete search would need to dispatch events every keydown.  Im talking about simple input forms that are less components and more static.

Comment: FYI, this convo is interesting: http://blog.rangle.io/managing-state-redux-angular/#comment-2333118647

Comment: @UAvalos this is what Im basically saying. Its a case by case, and if you want to be that granular you can.  The problem when you have a 100 forms a user could interact with, do you really want to create 100 reducers?  If you do maybe looking into something like redux-form would help?  Not sure though, haven't used the library. Good discussion though.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "it depends". Also, the assumption is that you''re convinced of the benefits of one-way data flow and redux, so prefer redux over two-way data binding if given the choice.

1. Uber-simple form (no validation, no complex relationships with other state). Then you *could* "go naked" and directly hook up the inputs to redux. In our use case, we actually decided to go with Angular forms because we figured it handles edge cases (IE and safari mobile).
2. Don't need every form change in redux state. Then the form submit can dispatch an action to update redux state. Things get tricky if the form needs to change in response to redux state. See below.
3. You do need every form change in redux state. Angular forms do not have a form#ng-change, so one strategy is to attach an ng-change to every input that dispatches an action to update the redux state. (Yes, it is error prone because it easy to forget to use ng-change, meanwhile the app appears to work.) Again, things get tricky if the form needs to change in response to redux state. See below.

### Updating the form in response to redux state change

The common use case is actually very simple. A concrete example will help---suppose the form tracks app settings, meanwhile `app settings` exist as redux state. That is, there is a two-way data binding between the Angular form and the redux state. *This is probably the common use case.*

In this case, the solution is to proceed as before: update redux state from the Angular form by dispatching update actions, and update the Angular form from redux state via #mapStateToThis.

```
  Angular ----dispatch actions----->  Redux
   Form  <----mapStateToThis--------  State
```

The only gotcha is to *not* pass the Redux state directly to the Angular form i.e., deep clone the data or use ImmutableJS.

The other common use case is to implement a "form reset", that is, reset the form to a "pristine" state after pressing a button, for example. Again, a concrete example will help:

> Suppose that `app state` (redux state) tracks whether the state is pristine via a flag `app.pristine`. (To clarify how `app.pristine` works, it works as expected, that is, it changes to false as soon as any value changes, and changes to true only when explicitly set to true.)

First, as far as I know, Angular doesn't automagically keep track of the "initial" state. You have to do it yourself and you may as well put that state in redux. Then, the initial form values are just the app settings when `app.pristine` is false. (If you're thinking of putting this in #mapStateToThis, don't. Doing side effects in a transform function seems weird.) A better way is to use an asynchronous action, namely the form onChange listener:

```
// thunk example
onFormChange(newForm) {

  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    const appSettings = getState().appSettings;
    const appIsPristine = appSettings.pristine;

    // this will fire once because the next action will set it to false
    appIsPristine && dispatch(initForm(appSettings)));
    dispatch(updateAppSettings(newForm));
  };
},
```

The reset action works as you would expect (which I won't outline).

To conclude, I should add that the above assumes that only the Angular form can dirty the app settings---otherwise, the initial form values may never be stored. If that's the case, then one idiomatic solution is to create a custom middleware that sets the initial form value whenever `app.pristine` changes to true. (Alternatively, use an Angular watch.)